# XCODE: Why can I not klick on all variables to inspect them?

Tags: xcode

I noticed using XCode's breakpoints that I can only klick on certain variables to get there current value (by the way: it even gives you a map for CLLocations - isn't that great?).
It seems no to be working for variables too far away from the breakpoint.

Is there a pattern to this? Can I advice XCode to give me values for all variables in the code?

Using XCode 7.01

Comment: Why would you want ALL the variables?

Comment: Sorry, of course I don't need ALL, but at least the once in the current class would be interesting.